# Are these formulas equivalent?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I am solving the problem from the textbook, and g) part states "There is exactly one person whom everybody loves." L(x, y) is "x loves y."

(1) The first and easiest solution is: $\exists !y\forall xL\left(x,y\right)$

(2) Then I came up with the second solution:
$\exists \:y\left(\forall \:x\left(L\left(x,\:y\right)\:\wedge \forall \:z\left(L\left(x,\:z\right)\rightarrow \left(z=y\right)\right)\right)\right)$
Which I **think** is also the correct one.

(3) The third solution is: $\exists x\left(\forall yL\left(y,\:x\right)\:\wedge \forall z\left(\left(z\ne x\right)\rightarrow \exists w\neg L\left(w,z\right)\right)\right)$

(4) And the solution from the book is: $\exists x\left(\forall yL\left(y,x\right)\wedge \forall z\left(\left(\forall wL\left(w,z\right)\right)\rightarrow z=x\right)\right)$

Is the (2) second formula correct in this case? and if so, are they equivalent?

Comment: They don't have a lot of differences, but as we can see there is additional  ∀w in (4), which I think is unnecessary, and we can use only ∀x as (2) one shows us.

Comment: #4 is just a full translation of #1 (since the "unique existence" quantifier can be expressed in terms of the standard existential and universal quantifiers), and #3 is just contrapositive applied to #4. The only one that is truly wrong is #2, as the provided answer explains (it says there exists a person which is loved by everyone and is the only person anyone loves)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct. $\forall z (L(x,z) \rightarrow (z=y))$ means that if someone loves $z$, that person must be person $y$. Which means that someone can only love person $y$ and no one else. However, "There is exactly one person whom everybody loves." means that there is one person loved by everybody and no other person is loved by **everybody**. This does not imply that everyone only loves 1 person, which is what you encoded in your formula.

The difference with eq. 4 is that it is now stated that: "if someone is loved by everyone, the person must be person z.". Note that this does not state that everyone only loves 1 person. The forall part **is necessary** in this case.

A good way to see if you translation is correct is to translate your formula back to English and see how well it matches the original sentence.

Comment: I read your entire answer, and I agree with you that it's useful to try translate the formula to English, but if we do so, then we will see that they are the same.
The (2) one states: There exists y for all x such that every x loves y and for every pair x and z, if x loves z, then z equals y. If I have any incorrect conclusions let me know ;)

Comment: The commenter on your original post provided an excellent translation to English. Using that translation it'll be easier to understand why your formula does not match the original statement.

Comment: So as I understand I wrote something like "Every person likes y and one y.", didn't it?

Comment: If you change "one" to "only", yes

Comment: Yes, it's just a typo, again thanks a lot :)